# Linux rename files as dirname

Tags: linux, bash, find, rename

i got lots of files like this:

```
./1/wwuhw.mp3
./2/nweiewe.mp3
./3/iwqjoiw.mp3
./4/ncionw.MP3
./5/joiwqfm.wmv
./6/jqoifiew.WMV
```

how can i rename them like this in Linux Bash:

```
./1/1.mp3
./2/2.mp3
./3/3.mp3
./4/4.MP3
./5/5.wmv
./6/6.WMV
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. However, your question fails to be on topic for Stack Overflow as it is not pertaining to a particular programming problem. Please take a look at [help/on-topic]. If you are able to modify your question to remain on-topic, please take a look at [ask] and [mcve] for information on how best to do this. Otherwise, you might want to take a look at [unix.se] and [su] for information on file manipulation and the linux bash system.

Comment: This question is about scripting and fine here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
for i in */*; do mv $i $(dirname $i)/$(dirname $i).${i##*.}; done
```

`For` loop iterates over each file in directory one by one. and `mv` statement renames the each file in directory one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job:

```
for i in */*; do
    echo mv "${i}" "${i%/*}/${i%/*}.${i##*.}"
done
```

See e.g. [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal), what this cryptic parameter expansions (like `${i%/*}`) mean in `bash`.

The script above will only print the commands in the console, without invoking them. Once you are sure you want to proceed, you can remove the `echo` statement and let it run.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using external tool, then [rnm](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm) can do this pretty easily:

```
rnm -ns '/pd0/./e/' */*
```

`/pd0/` is the immediate parent directory, `/pd1/` is the directory before that and so forth.

`-ns` means *name string* and `/pd/` and `/e/` are *name string rules* which expands to *parent directory* and *file extension* respectively.

The general format of the `/pd/` rule is `/pd<digit>-<digit>-<delim>/`, for example, a rule like `/pd0-2-_/` will construct `dir0_dir1_dir2` from a directory structure of `dir2/dir1/dir0`

More examples can be found [here](https://neurobin.org/docs/unix/rnm).

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop method, as outlined in some of the other answers, would suffice and work great for most cases where you need to rename *every* file in a directory to the first parent's directory name. My particular case called for a bit more granularity, where I only wanted to rename a *subset* of the files in a directory and assert that the operand was, in fact, an actual *file*, not an empty directory, symbolic link, etc. Using `find` can achieve exactly what you want in addition to the added ability to apply filtration and processing to the file inputs and outputs.

```
#####################################
# Same effect as using a `for` loop #
#####################################
#
#   -mindepth 2 : ensures that the file has a parent directory.
#   -type f : ensures that we are working with a `regular file` (not directory, symlink, etc.).

find . -mindepth 2 -type f -exec bash -c 'file="{}"; dir="$(dirname $file)"; mv "$file" "$dir/${dir##*/}.${file##*.}"' \;

#########################
# Additional filtration # 
#########################

# mp3 ONLY (case insensitive) 
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -iname "*.mp3" -exec bash -c 'file="{}"; dir="$(dirname $file)"; mv "$file" "$dir/${dir##*/}.${file##*.}"' \;

# mp3 OR mp4 ONLY (case insensitive)
find . -mindepth 2 -type f \( -iname "*.mp3" -or -iname "*.mp4" \) -exec bash -c 'file="{}"; "dir=$(dirname $file)"; mv "$file" "$dir/${dir##*/}.${file##*.}"' \;
```